# Sankey Diagram (Alluvial Diagram) in Vega-lite

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite, vega, sankey-diagram

Anyone having an idea on how to create Sankey diagrams like those in Vega-lite?

https://observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram
[image]

Input would be data like

`From | To | Amount`

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to implement this?

Comment: No, not in Vega-lite.

Comment: So did you use some other Kibana visualisation for it, or is it just not possible in Kibana?

Comment: Haven't tried with Kibana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the blog post from Yuri Astrakhan, I created the following in Vega.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.2.json",
  "height": 300,
  "width": 600,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "rawData",
      "values": [
        {"key": {"stk1": "aa", "stk2": "cc"}, "doc_count": 7},
        {"key": {"stk1": "aa", "stk2": "bb"}, "doc_count": 4},
        {"key": {"stk1": "bb", "stk2": "aa"}, "doc_count": 8},
        {"key": {"stk1": "bb", "stk2": "bb"}, "doc_count": 6},
        {"key": {"stk1": "bb", "stk2": "cc"}, "doc_count": 3},
        {"key": {"stk1": "cc", "stk2": "aa"}, "doc_count": 9}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.key.stk1", "as": "stk1"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.key.stk2", "as": "stk2"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.doc_count", "as": "size"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodes",
      "source": "rawData",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "!groupSelector || groupSelector.stk1 == datum.stk1 || groupSelector.stk2 == datum.stk2"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.stk1+datum.stk2", "as": "key"},
        {"type": "fold", "fields": ["stk1", "stk2"], "as": ["stack", "grpId"]},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1' ? datum.stk1+' '+datum.stk2 : datum.stk2+' '+datum.stk1",
          "as": "sortField"
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "sortField", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "size"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "(datum.y0+datum.y1)/2", "as": "yc"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "groups",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["stack", "grpId"],
          "fields": ["size"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "as": ["total"]
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "grpId", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "total"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "scale('y', datum.y0)", "as": "scaledY0"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "scale('y', datum.y1)", "as": "scaledY1"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1'",
          "as": "rightLabel"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.total/domain('y')[1]",
          "as": "percentage"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "destinationNodes",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk2'"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "edges",
      "source": "nodes",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.stack == 'stk1'"},
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "destinationNodes",
          "key": "key",
          "fields": ["key"],
          "as": ["target"]
        },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": "diagonal",
          "sourceY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.yc)"},
          "sourceX": {"expr": "scale('x', 'stk1') + bandwidth('x')"},
          "targetY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.target.yc)"},
          "targetX": {"expr": "scale('x', 'stk2')"}
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "range('y')[0]-scale('y', datum.size)",
          "as": "strokeWidth"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.size/domain('y')[1]",
          "as": "percentage"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": ["stk1", "stk2"],
      "paddingOuter": 0.05,
      "paddingInner": 0.95
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "nodes", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "rawData", "field": "stk1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "stackNames",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": ["Source", "Destination"],
      "domain": ["stk1", "stk2"]
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "scale": "x",
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {"text": {"scale": "stackNames", "field": "value"}}
        }
      }
    },
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "y"}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "name": "edgeMark",
      "from": {"data": "edges"},
      "clip": true,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "stroke": [
            {
              "test": "groupSelector && groupSelector.stack=='stk1'",
              "scale": "color",
              "field": "stk2"
            },
            {"scale": "color", "field": "stk1"}
          ],
          "strokeWidth": {"field": "strokeWidth"},
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "strokeOpacity": {
            "signal": "!groupSelector && (groupHover.stk1 == datum.stk1 || groupHover.stk2 == datum.stk2) ? 0.9 : 0.3"
          },
          "zindex": {
            "signal": "!groupSelector && (groupHover.stk1 == datum.stk1 || groupHover.stk2 == datum.stk2) ? 1 : 0"
          },
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum.stk1 + ' → ' + datum.stk2 + '    ' + format(datum.size, ',.0f') + '   (' + format(datum.percentage, '.1%') + ')'"
          }
        },
        "hover": {"strokeOpacity": {"value": 1}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "name": "groupMark",
      "from": {"data": "groups"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "grpId"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "y": {"field": "scaledY0"},
          "y2": {"field": "scaledY1"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.6},
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum.grpId + '   ' + format(datum.total, ',.0f') + '   (' + format(datum.percentage, '.1%') + ')'"
          }
        },
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "groups"},
      "interactive": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {
            "signal": "scale('x', datum.stack) + (datum.rightLabel ? bandwidth('x') + 8 : -8)"
          },
          "yc": {"signal": "(datum.scaledY0 + datum.scaledY1)/2"},
          "align": {"signal": "datum.rightLabel ? 'left' : 'right'"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"},
          "text": {
            "signal": "abs(datum.scaledY0-datum.scaledY1) > 13 ? datum.grpId : ''"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "group",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "dataForShowAll",
          "values": [{}],
          "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "groupSelector"}]
        }
      ],
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"signal": "width/2"},
          "y": {"value": 30},
          "width": {"value": 80},
          "height": {"value": 30}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "group",
          "name": "groupReset",
          "from": {"data": "dataForShowAll"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "cornerRadius": {"value": 6},
              "fill": {"value": "#f5f5f5"},
              "stroke": {"value": "#c1c1c1"},
              "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
              "height": {"field": {"group": "height"}},
              "width": {"field": {"group": "width"}}
            },
            "update": {"opacity": {"value": 1}},
            "hover": {"opacity": {"value": 0.7}}
          },
          "marks": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "interactive": false,
              "encode": {
                "enter": {
                  "xc": {"field": {"group": "width"}, "mult": 0.5},
                  "yc": {
                    "field": {"group": "height"},
                    "mult": 0.5,
                    "offset": 2
                  },
                  "align": {"value": "center"},
                  "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
                  "fontWeight": {"value": "bold"},
                  "text": {"value": "Show All"}
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "nodes"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#000"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1},
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "y": {"field": "y0", "scale": "y"},
          "y2": {"field": "y1", "scale": "y"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "groupHover",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@groupMark:mouseover",
          "update": "{stk1:datum.stack=='stk1' && datum.grpId, stk2:datum.stack=='stk2' && datum.grpId}"
        },
        {"events": "mouseout", "update": "{}"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "groupSelector",
      "value": false,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "@groupMark:click!",
          "update": "{stack:datum.stack, stk1:datum.stack=='stk1' && datum.grpId, stk2:datum.stack=='stk2' && datum.grpId}"
        },
        {
          "events": [
            {"type": "click", "markname": "groupReset"},
            {"type": "dblclick"}
          ],
          "update": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I decided to create a proper Sankey diagram in Vega. You can see the code here: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "Sankey Chart by David Bacci: https://www.linkedin.com/in/davbacci/",
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 800,
  "padding": {"bottom": 20, "left": 20, "right": 30, "top": 40},
  "title": {
    "text": "Microsoft's FY23 Q2 Income Statement",
    "color": "#005ca5",
    "fontSize": 32,
    "dy": 0,
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "offset": 30
  },
  "background": "#fafafa",
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "standardGap",
      "value": 14,
      "description": "Gap as a percentage of full domain"
    },
    {
      "name": "base",
      "value": "center",
      "description": "How to stack(center or zero)"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "input",
      "values": [
        {
          "category": "Server Products & Cloud",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 1,
          "labels": "left"
        },
        {
          "category": "Enterprise Services",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 2,
          "labels": "left",
          "gap": 20
        },
        {
          "category": "Office Products",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 3,
          "labels": "left"
        },
        {"category": "LinkedIn", "stack": 1, "sort": 4, "labels": "left"},
        {"category": "Other", "stack": 1, "sort": 5, "labels": "left"},
        {"category": "Windows", "stack": 1, "sort": 6, "labels": "left"},
        {"category": "Gaming", "stack": 1, "sort": 7, "labels": "left"},
        {
          "category": "Search & News Advertising",
          "stack": 1,
          "sort": 8,
          "labels": "left"
        },
        {"category": "Devices", "stack": 1, "sort": 9, "labels": "left"},
        {"category": "Intelligent Cloud", "stack": 2, "sort": 1},
        {"category": "Productivity", "stack": 2, "sort": 2},
        {"category": "Personal Computing", "stack": 2, "sort": 3},
        {"category": "Revenue", "stack": 3},
        {"category": "Gross Profit", "stack": 4, "sort": 1, "gap": 30},
        {"category": "Cost of Revenue", "stack": 4, "sort": 2, "gap": 30},
        {"category": "Operating Profit", "stack": 5, "sort": 1, "gap": 60},
        {"category": "Operating Expenses", "stack": 5, "sort": 2, "gap": 30},
        {"category": "Product Costs", "stack": 5, "sort": 3, "gap": 20},
        {"category": "Service Costs", "stack": 5, "sort": 4, "gap": 20},
        {"category": "Net Profit", "stack": 6, "sort": 1, "gap": 0},
        {"category": "Tax", "stack": 6, "sort": 2, "gap": 0},
        {"category": "R&D", "stack": 6, "sort": 3, "gap": 20},
        {"category": "S&M", "stack": 6, "sort": 4, "gap": 0},
        {"category": "G&A", "stack": 6, "sort": 5, "gap": 0},
        {
          "source": "Server Products & Cloud",
          "destination": "Intelligent Cloud",
          "value": 19.6
        },
        {
          "source": "Enterprise Services",
          "destination": "Intelligent Cloud",
          "value": 1.9
        },
        {
          "source": "Office Products",
          "destination": "Productivity",
          "value": 11.8
        },
        {"source": "LinkedIn", "destination": "Productivity", "value": 3.9},
        {"source": "Other", "destination": "Productivity", "value": 1.3},
        {
          "source": "Windows",
          "destination": "Personal Computing",
          "value": 4.8
        },
        {"source": "Gaming", "destination": "Personal Computing", "value": 4.8},
        {
          "source": "Search & News Advertising",
          "destination": "Personal Computing",
          "value": 3.2
        },
        {
          "source": "Devices",
          "destination": "Personal Computing",
          "value": 1.4
        },
        {
          "source": "Intelligent Cloud",
          "destination": "Revenue",
          "value": 21.5
        },
        {"source": "Productivity", "destination": "Revenue", "value": 17},
        {
          "source": "Personal Computing",
          "destination": "Revenue",
          "value": 14.2
        },
        {"source": "Revenue", "destination": "Gross Profit", "value": 35.2},
        {"source": "Revenue", "destination": "Cost of Revenue", "value": 17.5},
        {
          "source": "Gross Profit",
          "destination": "Operating Profit",
          "value": 20.4
        },
        {
          "source": "Gross Profit",
          "destination": "Operating Expenses",
          "value": 14.8
        },
        {
          "source": "Cost of Revenue",
          "destination": "Product Costs",
          "value": 5.7
        },
        {
          "source": "Cost of Revenue",
          "destination": "Service Costs",
          "value": 11.8
        },
        {
          "source": "Operating Profit",
          "destination": "Net Profit",
          "value": 16.4
        },
        {"source": "Operating Profit", "destination": "Tax", "value": 3.9},
        {"source": "Operating Expenses", "destination": "R&D", "value": 6.8},
        {"source": "Operating Expenses", "destination": "S&M", "value": 5.7},
        {"source": "Operating Expenses", "destination": "G&A", "value": 2.3}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "stacks",
      "source": "input",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.source != null"},
        {"type": "formula", "as": "end", "expr": "['source','destination']"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "name",
          "expr": "[ datum.source,datum.destination]"
        },
        {"type": "project", "fields": ["end", "name", "value"]},
        {"type": "flatten", "fields": ["end", "name"]},
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "input",
          "key": "category",
          "values": ["stack", "sort", "gap", "labels"],
          "fields": ["name"],
          "as": ["stack", "sort", "gap", "labels"]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": ["value", "stack", "sort", "gap", "labels"],
          "groupby": ["end", "name"],
          "ops": ["sum", "max", "max", "max", "max"],
          "as": ["value", "stack", "sort", "gap", "labels"]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": ["value", "stack", "sort", "gap", "labels"],
          "groupby": ["name"],
          "ops": ["max", "max", "max", "max", "max"],
          "as": ["value", "stack", "sort", "gap", "labels"]
        },
        {"type": "formula", "as": "gap", "expr": "datum.gap?datum.gap:0"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "maxValue",
      "source": ["stacks"],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": ["value"],
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "as": ["value"]
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "fields": ["value"],
          "ops": ["max"],
          "as": ["value"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "plottedStacks",
      "source": ["stacks"],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "spacer",
          "expr": " (data('maxValue')[0].value/100)*(standardGap+datum.gap)"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "as": "type", "expr": "['data','spacer']"},
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "as": "spacedValue",
          "expr": "[datum.value,datum.spacer]"
        },
        {"type": "flatten", "fields": ["type", "spacedValue"]},
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["stack"],
          "sort": {"field": "sort", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "spacedValue",
          "offset": {"signal": "base"}
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "((datum.value)/2)+datum.y0", "as": "yc"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "finalTable",
      "source": ["plottedStacks"],
      "transform": [{"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.type == 'data'"}]
    },
    {
      "name": "linkTable",
      "source": ["input"],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.source != null"},
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "finalTable",
          "key": "name",
          "values": ["y0", "y1", "stack", "sort"],
          "fields": ["source"],
          "as": ["sourceStacky0", "sourceStacky1", "sourceStack", "sourceSort"]
        },
        {
          "type": "lookup",
          "from": "finalTable",
          "key": "name",
          "values": ["y0", "y1", "stack", "sort"],
          "fields": ["destination"],
          "as": [
            "destinationStacky0",
            "destinationStacky1",
            "destinationStack",
            "destinationSort"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["source"],
          "sort": {"field": "destinationSort", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "value",
          "offset": "zero",
          "as": ["syi0", "syi1"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.syi0+datum.sourceStacky0",
          "as": "sy0"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.sy0+datum.value", "as": "sy1"},
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "groupby": ["destination"],
          "sort": {"field": "sourceSort", "order": "descending"},
          "field": "value",
          "offset": "zero",
          "as": ["dyi0", "dyi1"]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.dyi0+datum.destinationStacky0",
          "as": "dy0"
        },
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "datum.dy0+datum.value", "as": "dy1"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "((datum.value)/2)+datum.sy0", "as": "syc"},
        {"type": "formula", "expr": "((datum.value)/2)+datum.dy0", "as": "dyc"},
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "orient": "horizontal",
          "shape": "diagonal",
          "sourceY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.syc)"},
          "sourceX": {
            "expr": "scale('x', toNumber(  datum.sourceStack))+ bandwidth('x')"
          },
          "targetY": {"expr": "scale('y', datum.dyc)"},
          "targetX": {"expr": "scale('x', datum.destinationStack)"}
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "range('y')[0]-scale('y', datum.value)",
          "as": "strokeWidth"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "finalTable", "field": "stack"},
      "paddingInner": 0.88
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "finalTable", "field": "y1"},
      "reverse": false
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": {"scheme": "rainbow"},
      "domain": {"data": "stacks", "field": "name"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "finalTable"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "stack"},
          "width": {"scale": "x", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.75},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0},
          "stroke": {"scale": "color", "field": "name"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{'Name':datum.name, 'Value':format(datum.value, '$') + 'B'}"
          },
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "name": "links",
      "from": {"data": "linkTable"},
      "clip": true,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "strokeWidth": {"field": "strokeWidth"},
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"signal": "0.3"},
          "stroke": {"field": "destination", "scale": "color"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 1},
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "{'Source':datum.source,'Destination':datum.destination, 'Value':format(datum.value, '$') + 'B'}"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "group",
      "name": "labelText",
      "zindex": 1,
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "data": "finalTable",
          "name": "labelFacet",
          "groupby": ["name", "stack", "yc", "value", "labels"]
        }
      },
      "clip": false,
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 1},
          "stroke": {"value": "red"},
          "x": {
            "signal": "datum.labels=='left'?scale('x', datum.stack)-8 : scale('x', datum.stack) + (bandwidth('x')) +8"
          },
          "yc": {"scale": "y", "signal": "datum.yc"},
          "width": {"signal": "0"},
          "height": {"signal": "0"},
          "fillOpacity": {"signal": "0.1"}
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "heading",
          "from": {"data": "labelFacet"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "x": {"value": 0},
              "y": {"value": -2},
              "text": {"field": "name"},
              "align": {"signal": "datum.labels=='left'?'right':'left'"},
              "fontWeight": {"value": "normal"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "name": "amount",
          "from": {"data": "labelFacet"},
          "encode": {
            "update": {
              "x": {"value": 0},
              "y": {"value": 12},
              "text": {"signal": " format(datum.value, '$') + 'B'"},
              "align": {"signal": "datum.labels=='left'?'right':'left'"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "labelText"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "bounds.x1", "offset": -2},
          "x2": {"field": "bounds.x2", "offset": 2},
          "y": {"field": "bounds.y1", "offset": -2},
          "y2": {"field": "bounds.y2", "offset": 2},
          "fill": {"value": "white"},
          "opacity": {"value": 0.8},
          "cornerRadius": {"value": 4}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "data": [{}],
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "text": {
            "value": [
              "Source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/investor/earnings/fy-2023-q2/income-statements",
              "Dataviz: David Bacci"
            ]
          },
          "align": {"value": "left"},
          "lineHeight": {"value": 16},
          "fill": {"value": "#595959"},
          "x": {"signal": "-150"},
          "y": {"signal": "height +70"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 10}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "text": {"fontSize": 13, "fill": "#333333"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit dated, but this blog post shows how to do this kind of 'Sankey' diagram within Kibana using the 'Vega' visualisations.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/sankey-visualization-with-vega-in-kibana

I've played with it a bit a few years ago; it's possible certainly, and rewarding, but that complexity does come at a cost.