# Deploying Sankey Chart Visualization in Palantir Foundry

Tags: sankey-diagram

Do we have something simple and fast in Palantir for sankey visualisation. For inspiration i have found a similar link under [Sankey Diagram (Alluvial Diagram) in Vega-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387154/sankey-diagram-alluvial-diagram-in-vega-lite)

Also is it possible to have a multi layer sankey diagram with source-->target1 , target1--> target2 ,target2--> target3 etc.

Please advice

I have already tried the sankey diagram in power Bi with a single source and single target. But i have a huge dataset in foundry which i want to utilize in similar data flow fashion.